# Why won't my bootstrap run on a hostgators servers?

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap website that runs very well locally, but when I upload it to hostgator, through cpanel, it stays loading. Here is the url [www.universitymmt.com](http://www.universitymmt.com)

Here is the file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">

  <title>MMT University</title>
  <meta content="" name="descriptison">
  <meta content="" name="keywords">

  <!-- Favicons -->
  <link href="assets/img/favicon.png" rel="icon">
  <link href="assets/img/apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon">

  <!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i|Montserrat:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i|Poppins:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Vendor CSS Files -->
  <link href="assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/icofont/icofont.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/boxicons/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/venobox/venobox.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/remixicon/remixicon.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/owl.carousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/aos/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Template Main CSS File -->
  <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- =======================================================
  * Template Name: Bootslander - v2.2.0
  * Template URL: https://bootstrapmade.com/bootslander-free-bootstrap-landing-page-template/
  * Author: BootstrapMade.com
  * License: https://bootstrapmade.com/license/
  ======================================================== -->
</head>

<body>

  <!-- ======= Header ======= -->
  <header id="header" class="fixed-top d-flex align-items-center header-transparent">
    <div class="container d-flex align-items-center">

      <div class="logo mr-auto">
        <img src="assets/img/logo-solo.png" class="img-fluid"/>
        <!-- Uncomment below if you prefer to use an image logo -->
        <!-- <a href="index.html"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="" class="img-fluid"></a>-->
      </div>

      <nav class="nav-menu d-none d-lg-block">
        <ul>
          <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">Quem somos</a></li>
          <li><a href="#details">Onde atuamos</a></li>
          <li><a href="#servicos">Servicos</a></li>
          <li><a href="#gallery">Depoimentos</a></li>
          <li><a href="#pricing">Comecando</a></li>
          <li><a href="#faq">Contacte-nos</a></li>
          <li><a class="btn-get-started2 scrollto" rel="modal:open" key="login" id="myBtn">Acessar</a></li>
          
          

        </ul>
      </nav><!-- .nav-menu -->

    </div>
  </header><!-- End Header -->

  <!-- ======= Hero Section ======= -->
  <section id="hero">

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-7 pt-5 pt-lg-0 order-2 order-lg-1 d-flex align-items-center">
          <div data-aos="zoom-out">
            <h1>Bem vindo à <span>MMT University</span></h1>
            <h2>LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET, CONSECTETUR ADIPISICING ELIT,
              SED DO EIUSMOD TEMPOR INCIDIDUNT UT LABORE ET DOLORE MAGNA ALIQUA.
              </h2>
            <div class="text-center text-lg-left">
              <a href="#about" class="btn-get-started scrollto" rel="modal:open" key="login" id="myBtn">Começar</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-5 order-1 order-lg-2 hero-img" data-aos="zoom-out" data-aos-delay="300">
          <img src="assets/img/bannerthumb.png" class="img-fluid animated" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <svg class="hero-waves" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 24 150 28 " preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <defs>
        <path id="wave-path" d="M-160 44c30 0 58-18 88-18s 58 18 88 18 58-18 88-18 58 18 88 18 v44h-352z">
      </defs>
      <g class="wave1">
        <use xlink:href="#wave-path" x="50" y="3" fill="rgba(255,255,255, .1)">
      </g>
      <g class="wave2">
        <use xlink:href="#wave-path" x="50" y="0" fill="rgba(255,255,255, .2)">
      </g>
      <g class="wave3">
        <use xlink:href="#wave-path" x="50" y="9" fill="#fff">
      </g>
    </svg>

  </section><!-- End Hero -->
```

Lets say the code is just that. It wont run and it keeps loading a green circle.
I checked with support and they said it must be an error inside my scripts.

Comment: You are missing the **main.js at [/assets/js/main.js](https://www.universitymmt.com/assets/js/main.js)** and **validate.js at [/assets/vendor/php-email-form/validate.js](https://www.universitymmt.com/assets/vendor/php-email-form/validate.js)** these prevent your site to load!

Comment: @thốngnguyễn That worked!!! Thanks a lot man.

Comment: Please to help!

Comment: @thốngnguyễn Please turn your comment into an answer so that Tomas Mota can select it as the correct answer to close out this question. *Thanks!*

Comment: @cssyphus i'm done. But can you please tell me why this is necessary? - I'm new and i just don't understand!

Comment: The genius of StackOverflow is that Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky turned the standard question/answer peer-assist bulletin board into a game (complete with badges, statistics and ranking). Answerers *compete* for reputation points and seek to rise in the rankings, which are now [recognized outside the game](https://v.gd/kXEkER). When questions are answered via comments, two negative things occur: (1) the question is not closed, it remains open, and

Comment: (2) undeserving users will post the answer given in the comment as their own - and in order for the question to be closed, it will eventually be selected as the correct answer. We would rather reward the person who first found the answer. In this case, you. Hurray for you! :)

Comment: As you use it, remember that StackOverflow is this "game" that works by upvotes and checkmarks (choosing the correct answer). Upvotes and checkmarks cost you nothing, so be generous. And ask lots and lots (within reason) of questions - the more questions you ask, the more people who can participate/contribute.

Comment: In particular, SO is not designed to facilitate conversations via comments. Ask a question. Choose an answer. Ask another question. Thus, instead of one person seeing your next question (via the comment - and, really, being obliged to answer two questions for the price of one), dozens will see the new question and try to assist. That helps you (MUCH faster response), and it helps them (faster reward). As in everything, use your noggin - if the answer provided is not clear or NOT the answer, a comment is justified. If it answers your question, but you want to fine-tune it, ask a new question -

Comment: - then post the URL to that new question (via comment) below the prev answer, so the prev answerer has the option to find it and assist. Re upvotes: I am not saying to go crazy and upvote almost everything - don't be that guy. But if an answer is given that doesn't quite solve the problem in your question, *but does provide useful information* - upvote. Award the checkmark to the deserving answer *(if it is especially helpful or well-written, checkmark* **and** *upvote)*, but make sure that other answers with useful information are also rewarded - especially when upvotes cost nothing to give.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the main.js at [/assets/js/main.js](https://www.universitymmt.com/assets/js/main.js) and validate.js at [/assets/vendor/php-email-form/validate.js](https://www.universitymmt.com/assets/vendor/php-email-form/validate.js) these prevent your site to load!